# Converting IEEE 754 64 bit to decimal

Tags: python

I have a list of 64-bit IEEE-754 hex values, stored as strings, that I want to convert to python `float`:

```
['40D3970060AA64C3', ...]
```

I've have tried to use `binascii.unhexlify and`struct.unpack` to convert each string, but it fails since this is 64 bit.

I can get it to work with 32 bit hex values:

```
import binascii
import struct

hex_list = ['40D38700', '40D64700', '40E79700']

for i, value in enumerate(hex_list, 0):
    print(struct.unpack('<f', binascii.unhexlify(hex_list[i].replace(' ', ''))))
```

Result:

```
(1.24735742022795e-38,)
(6.597178645388664e-39,)
(1.3950116788944702e-38,)
```

When I go to 64 bit:

```
import binascii
import struct

hex_list_64 = ['40D3970060AA64C3', '40D3970060AA64C3', '40D3970060AA64C3']

for i, value in enumerate(hex_list_64, 0):
    print(struct.unpack('<d', binascii.unhexlify(hex_list_64[i].replace(' ', ''))))
```

Result:

```
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
```

However, converting `40D3970060AA64C3` to binary is supposed to yield `2.00600059000000001105945557356E4`. Via, http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=40D3970060AA64C3

Comment: Use `d` for 64-bit floats. The `f` only works with 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you. New issue now -- the values I'm getting back are not correct. Edited original post.

Comment: Read about [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the byte order is reversed for your (and my) platform relative to how it was encoded:

```
for value in hex_list_64:
    print(struct.unpack('<d', binascii.unhexlify(value)))
```

```
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
(-4.653463070196378e+16,)
```

BUT

```
for value in hex_list_64:
    print(struct.unpack('>d', binascii.unhexlify(value)))

(20060.0059,)
(20060.0059,)
(20060.0059,)
```

This makes sense, since Intel generally stores everything in little-endian order internally, while the string, if interpreted as read, is by definition in big endian.

Comment: What if I wanted to get more decimals from the conversion?

Comment: @Cowboysforlife. The entire number is stored in a `float`. If you want to print more, print something like `'{:.15g}'.format(blah)`. It's just a display issue, not an internal representation one.